# Compare multiple columns in SQL Server returning largest version by product

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005, I am attempting to write a select statement which will query the data below (18000 rows) and return one row per Product, finding the largest product version.

I think the query needs to compare the versions in reverse, and storing the largest row number as it gets up to Major but I am not sure.

**Sample Data**

```
    Product  Date       Major  Minor  Release Fixpack Build
    =======  ========== ====== ====== ======  ======  ======
    Widgets  01/01/2012 10     1      0       345     132
    Widgets  04/02/2011 6      6      3       932     245
    Widgets  09/01/2010 4      92     345     53      2
    Gears    03/17/2011 9      2      3       0       21
    Gears    12/12/2012 10     0      0       5       548
    Tires    04/24/2000 8      3      456     3       984
    Tires    04/12/1993 7      14     45      35      252
```

**Expected Results**

```
    Product  Date       Major  Minor  Release Fixpack Build
    =======  ========== ====== ====== ======  ======  ======
    Widgets  01/01/2012 10     1      0       345     132
    Gears    12/12/2012 10     0      0       5       548
    Tires    04/24/2000 8      3      456     3       984
```

OR even better, could combine the versions into one column:

```
    Product  Date       ProductVersion
    =======  ========== ==================
    Widgets  01/01/2012 10.1.0.345.132
    Gears    12/12/2012 10.0.0.5.548
    Tires    04/24/2000 8.3.456.3.984
```

Comment: can you show the product version table?

Comment: Date is just date or date time? if it is datetime then I think you can just do select top one Max major for each product with latest datetime. That will make sure that you will get latest version for each product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function in a derived table. Do the partition on `Product` and order by `Date desc` or your version information.

Ordered by `Date desc`:

```
select T.Product,
       T.Date,
       T.ProductVersion
from (
     select Product,
            Date,
            cast(Major as varchar(5))+'.'+
            cast(Minor as varchar(5))+'.'+
            cast(Release as varchar(5))+'.'+
            cast(Fixpack as varchar(5))+'.'+
            cast(Build as varchar(5)) as ProductVersion,
            row_number() over(partition by Product order by Date desc) as rn
     from YourTable
     ) as T
where T.rn = 1
```

Ordered by `ProductVersion desc`

```
select T.Product,
       T.Date,
       T.ProductVersion
from (
     select Product,
            Date,
            cast(Major as varchar(5))+'.'+
            cast(Minor as varchar(5))+'.'+
            cast(Release as varchar(5))+'.'+
            cast(Fixpack as varchar(5))+'.'+
            cast(Build as varchar(5)) as ProductVersion,
            row_number() over(partition by Product 
                              order by Major desc, 
                                       Minor desc, 
                                       Release desc, 
                                       Fixpack desc, 
                                       Build desc) as rn
     from YourTable
     ) as T
where T.rn = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8008/1)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT a.product, 
       a.md, 
       b.major, 
       b.minor, 
       b.release, 
       b.fixpack, 
       b.build 
FROM   (SELECT product, 
               Max(date) AS md 
        FROM   tbl 
        GROUP  BY product) a 
       JOIN tbl b 
         ON b.product = a.product 
            AND b.date = a.md
```

**Result**

```
| PRODUCT |         MD | MAJOR | MINOR | RELEASE | FIXPACK | BUILD |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Widgets | 2012-01-01 |    10 |     1 |       0 |     345 |   132 |
|   Tires | 2000-04-24 |     8 |     3 |     456 |       3 |   984 |
|   Gears | 2012-12-12 |    10 |     0 |       0 |       5 |   548 |
```

**Even better method**

```
SELECT a.product, 
       a.md                          AS date, 
       Cast(b.major AS VARCHAR(5)) + '.' 
       + Cast(b.minor AS VARCHAR(5)) + '.' 
       + Cast(b.release AS VARCHAR(5)) + '.' 
       + Cast(b.fixpack AS VARCHAR(5)) + '.' 
       + Cast(b.build AS VARCHAR(5)) AS version 
FROM   (SELECT product, 
               Max(date) AS md 
        FROM   tbl 
        GROUP  BY product) a 
       JOIN tbl b 
         ON b.product = a.product 
            AND b.date = a.md
```

```
| PRODUCT |       DATE |        VERSION |
-----------------------------------------
| Widgets | 2012-01-01 | 10.1.0.345.132 |
|   Tires | 2000-04-24 |  8.3.456.3.984 |
|   Gears | 2012-12-12 |   10.0.0.5.548 |
```